# Integral with DiracDelta. Can Mathematica be made to solve this?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This was an exam question.

$$
  \int_0^{2 \pi} \delta(\sin^2(\theta) -x ) \,d\theta
$$

Direct use of `Integrate` on it does not give the solution. Is there a trick or workaround? Here is the code I used

```
ClearAll[theta,x]
integrand = DiracDelta[Sin[theta]^2 - x]
Integrate[ integrand, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Here is the key solution analytical solution

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The solution uses this known [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) (half way down the Wikipedia page)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where the sum above is over all zeros of $g(x)$ in the integration interval. Mathematica does not seem to know this relation?

ps. Maple can't do it either.

Comment: The integral under consideration makes no sense in traditional math: DiracDelta is not a usual function, but a distribution (see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function as a first reading).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to give [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) assumptions:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[Sin[θ]^2-x], {θ, 0, 2 π}, Assumptions -> 0<x<1]
```

> 2/Sqrt[-(-1 + x) x]

Unfortunately, [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) is not quite smart enough to use the assumption `x ∈ Reals`:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[Sin[θ]^2-x], {θ, 0, 2 π}, Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals]
```

> Integrate[DiracDelta[-x + Sin[θ]^2], {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
>    Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals]

Comment: Nice! For some reason, this does not work for exponents other than `2` (e.g., `Sin[θ]^3 - x`). My code does not work either, presumably for the same reason (`Solve` is unable to determine the roots). Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform One hack is to replace `x` with `EulerGamma`, that will produce a result for `Sin[θ]^3 - x`, which you can then extrapolate into a generic answer.

Comment: The integral under consideration makes no sense in traditional math: DiracDelta is not a usual function, but a distribution (see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function as a first reading).

Answer (score 3):

```
f[θ_, x_] := Sin[θ]^2 - x
Derivative[1, 0][f][θ, x] /. Solve[{f[θ, x] == 0, 0 < θ < 2 π}, θ, Reals]
Integrate[DiracDelta[x - θ]/Abs[%], {θ, 0, 2 π}] // Total
```

[image]

This code should also work for other functions $f$, presumably.

Comment: You have an extra `[θ, x]`, and your `Solve` would work better if you added the domain `Reals`. Probably more robust than just relying on `Integrate`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Ah, yes, thank you!

Comment: The integral under consideration makes no sense in traditional math: DiracDelta is not a usual function, but a distribution (see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function as a first reading).